# Are tag badges disabled on this site?

Tags: bug, badges

It is more than 24 hours ago that I reached a count >100 on the tag "conlang-creation" but I did not receive a tag badge. I also notice that on the activity tab of my user page there is no possibility to switch between the tracking of priviledges and the tracking of tag badges.

Are tag badges disabled on this site? If so, why?

EDIT: Images from conlang and language learning—note the missing wheel in the conlang view

[image: Activity view from conlang.se] [image: Activity view from language learning.se]

Comment: Probably just caching/some other delay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A tag must appear on a minimum of 100 questions to be eligible for tag badges ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836/210480)). [conlang-creation](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conlang-creation), which is the most popular tag on the site, currently has only 38 questions, so this site is not yet eligible for any tag badges.